# jQuery mobile stops working with iFrame in the same page - Phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap

This is my Phonegap code:

```
<html>
    <head>      
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <style type="text/css">
             #footer{
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0px;">
        <!--<h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <p id="registration"></p>
        <ul id="pushList"></ul>-->
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page Title</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <iframe src="https://geckoadv.netsons.org/" style=" margin:0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;" > 
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->

        </div><!-- /page -->

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I add the `iFrame` inside my page jQuery Mobile stops working and the footer is not showing.
If I remove the `iFrame` everything works.

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: And I receive this error in Console: "[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 57ms"

Answer (score 0):

I was not closing the iFrame tag with `</iframe>`